# Identificate switch variable in assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I want to know the switch value that i think that is contained in %eax in the last instruction.
When the code reaches the point where it has to add 2 times the value of 20ebp to the value of 8ebp being if I am not mistaken 8ebp a pointer to short I don't agree with the add in line 14.

```
1. proc1:
2. pushl %ebp
3. movl %esp, %ebp
4. subl $24, %esp
5. movl 16(%ebp), %edx
6. movl 20(%ebp), %eax
7. movb %dl, -20(%ebp)
8. movb %al, -24(%ebp)
9. movl $0, -8(%ebp)
10. movl $1, -4(%ebp)
11. movzbl -24(%ebp), %eax
12. leal (%eax,%eax), %edx
13. movl 8(%ebp), %eax
14. addl %edx, %eax
15. movswl (%eax), %eax
16. addl $7, %eax
17. cmpl $8, %eax
18. ja .L2
19. movl .L4(,%eax,4), %eax
20. jmp *%eax
21.
22. .L4:
23. .long .L7
24. .long .L2
25. .long .L6
26. .long .L2
27. .long .L12
28. .long .L12
29. .long .L3
30. .long .L2
31. .long .L3
32. .text
```

> jut to make things clear I have to complete this C code

```
1. struct sta{
2. char c;
3. int L;
4. int M[3][5];
5. short V[5];
6. };
7. struct sta *V[6];
8. int K=4;
9. int proc1(short *vec, int mat[3][5],
unsigned char j, unsigned char i)
10. {
11. int x,y;
12. x=0;
13. y=1;
14. switch (______)
15. {
16. case ___:
17. if (______________________){
18. _________________;
19. }
20. break;
21. case ___:
22. for (___________________)
23. __________________;
24. break;
25. case ___:
26. case __;
27. while (_____){
28. _______________;
29. ______________;
30. ______________;
31. }
32. break;
33. case ___:
34. case ___:
35. _________________;
36. break;
37. default:
38. _______________;
39. break;
40. }
41. _________________;
42. }
43.
44.
45. void main(){
46. if (_________)
47. ______________________________;
48. else
49. _______________________________;
50. }
51.
```

I've been all day studying for tomorrow's exam and I couldn't do this exercise in all day

Comment: Make the program compile and look at the assembly, make some change and look at the diff. Btw `void main()` should be `int main(void)` to be portable.

Comment: Start by commenting each instruction, keeping track of the data as it moves between the registers and between the memory. You'll easily find the expression for the `switch`. As standing, your question is purely about solving a homework/assignment.

Comment: Just to be clear, a `switch` statement in C takes an expression, which could be a variable, but is not necessarily just a variable.

Comment: At line 14, the EDX value being added is 2x something else (note the LEA which wrote it), so I don't see any correctness problem adding that to a `short *`.  It's weird that it used `add` at all instead of an addressing mode like `movswl (%eax, %edx, 2), %eax` to save both the `add` and the earlier `leal (%eax,%eax), %edx` (instead load the index into EDX in the first place, instead of EAX; this looks like a debug build which is why it's doing other dumb stuff like copying the incoming stack args to below EBP.)